# Is it possible to Use Google Apps Script to check condition in Google Drive Forms?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

Is there a way to use google apps script to check if the specific input in a google form is a variable , number or a certain text ? If this conditions passes only then the user should be able to submit the form.

Comment: AFAIK, This is not possible even using Google Apps Script. All you can check if a field is required or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Forms does not support client-side validation like that, at this time.  Deploying an Apps Script as a web app would allow you to do it, but you have to create all of the formatting and functionality yourself.

The recent inclusion of [data validation functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-builder) in Apps Script in conjunction with Google Forms supporting [some scripting access](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/) means that we could see something along these lines in the future.  Would certainly go a long way toward making Google Forms more useful.